# Redefine default color of todonotes

Tags: macros, todonotes

I'm using the `todonotes` package with the article class to take class notes, and using the todos as markers (date, comments and so on) so I don't want to use the bright orange, which steals focus. I wanted to redefine the default color value as demonstrated in the todonotes readme (and change the color value to my liking):

```
\newcommand{\todoredefined}[2][]
{\todo[color=red, #1]{#2}}
```

But nothing changes. Here's a MWE with all the packages I have loaded, should they have some known problems with todonotes:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{gensymb}
\usepackage[icelandic]{babel} 
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}  
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{todonotes}
\usepackage{enumerate}
\usepackage{mhchem}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\newcommand{\todoredefined}[2][]
{\todo[color=red, #1]{#2}}

\begin{document}
    Something\todo{This should be red by now...}
\end{document}
```

When I compile this code I still get orange todos. Am I overlooking something or is this code sample obsolete?

Comment: Or you can look at this thread, [you can change the text color also] -> http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/254697/104909

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You get orange todos because you do not use your new command. The `todo` command is still defined as always, with orange background, but if you use your `todoredefined` command instead, the background will be red.

However, an easier way of doing this is to add `color=red` as an option to the package:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[color=red]{todonotes}

\begin{document}
Text \todo{Nothing}
\end{document}
```

Edit: You can set the color of the background, border and line from note to text separately, see the `todonotes` manual, section 1.2.

Comment: Ah.. It's always so embarrassing to find out what I did wrong :/